# BLE sensors pairing and get data

Tags: bluetooth

I have this sensors https://lonauto.en.alibaba.com/product/60692809352-806479288/4pcs_Sensor_one_set_intelligent_Tpms_tire_pressure_monitoring_system_free_app_on_iso_android_phone.html?spm=a2700.icbuShop.prewdfa4cf.7.1b29ca9abaaU3n from which I want to get some data over Bluetooth, it's low energy device which isn't discoverable - don't really know how pairing works at all so I need a lot of informations about pairing and everything. Any ideas would be welcome.

They have offcourse official app, but customer want custom app so therefore pairing should be in this custom app.

Answer (score 0):

[Bluetooth low energy overview AndroidDeveloperGuide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le)

This guide will help you with creating the logic for connecting and exchanging information from the Sensor.

Please follow all the `classes` mentioned in the Guide in detail, the various classes' `constant` variables and `methods` will give you good knowledge of what sorts of information you can get from the sensor.

Comment: But how actually pairing works, ble devices aren't discoverable over bluetooth?

Comment: The manufacturers may have set the sensor as non-discoverable. Please refer to Core Specifications Volume 3 Part C,GAP 9.2.2. I guess in this case, the Unique ID set by the manufacturers on the sensor corresponds to it's MAC address which is used to add the device in White List which can then be connected later.

Comment: Some progress currently i can discover device, but can't connect to it...

Comment: I see the developer guide has multiple ways to connect to the device using "transport" and "phy" variables, I am assuming they are using these in their default app. The good news is they are limited to a few values. I would run all the methods of BluetoothDevice and get all the information and also try all the cases to connectGatt().The cases are formed by guessing the values for 'transport" and "phy" variables. This is not an answer, it's just my guess.

Comment: Still no luck, try also few other BLE apps from Gplay store, but no one connect to sensor.